# Problem with fetching data from Parse Server using Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

I am trying to use Backbone.js to fetch data from a Parse Server instance. I've tested Parse and it's working. I can use curl and plain JavaScript on a web page to get data.

I get the following error in the Console:

```
Error:  TypeError: "Backbone.$.ajax is undefined"
Backbone 4
<anonymous> http://localhost:8000/js/tickets.js:28
jQuery 2
```

tickets.js:34:13
     http://localhost:8000/js/tickets.js:34
    jQuery 2

Line 28 is `myTickets = await myTickets.fetch();` in the code below.

I suspect that the issue is with the implementation of the url attribute in the collection. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
    $(async function() {


      Parse.initialize("exampleAppId", "");
      Parse.serverURL = "https://www.example.com/parse/";

      var Ticket = Parse.Object.extend("Ticket");

      var TicketCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Ticket,
        query: new Parse.Query(Ticket),
        url: function() {
          return "/classes/Ticket";
        }
      });

      var TicketsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile($("#tickets-tpl").html()),
        render: function() {
          var collection = { ticket: this.collection.toJSON() };
          this.$el.html(this.template(collection));
        }
      });

      var myTicketCollection = new TicketCollection();

      try {
        myTickets = await myTicketCollection.fetch();
        var ticketsView = new TicketsListView({ collection: myTickets });
        ticketsView.render();

        $(".main-container").html(ticketsView.el);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error: ", err);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I don't know if it has to do with the fact that you're passing in a `Parse.Object` as the `Backbone.Collection.model`. I'd try first to use a Backbone model via `Backbone.Model.extend`.

Comment: I think this is definitely an issue. Any hints on how to implement a Backbone model and View using Parse? I've been searching and I haven't found anything.

Comment: In fact I have been using Parse with Backbone for a while now, but have discarded Backbone.Models quite early because it was too complicated and bore little advantage. I manage data using Parse exclusively and rendering with Backbone.Views.

Comment: Any chance that you could post a simple example? Or point to one online? That would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry bro, that's not possible. But it's essentially fetching data via `Parse.Query('MyObject').find()` and routing to the desired View in Backbone.Router, then aggregating or calculating the fetched data in the view and rendering it with an underscore template, omitting Backbone.Collections and Backbone.Models altogether.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it was a big ask. :-). I'll keep on it ... and probably ask more questions.

Comment: Sure, go ahead, I'll contribute as best as I can

Answer (score 0):

> `Backbone.$.ajax` is undefined

Probably means you're not loading jQuery before Backbone

Comment: Thanks this was the issue. I did have jquery before backbone, but it was the slim, min version. I switched it to the min version and it resolved this error.